# Replace text without escaping in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, escaping, beautifulsoup

I would like to wrap some words that are not already links with anchor links in BeautifulSoup. I use this to achieve it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

text = ''' replace this string '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
pattern = 'replace'

for txt in soup.findAll(text=True):
    if re.search(pattern,txt,re.I) and txt.parent.name != 'a':
        newtext = re.sub(r'(%s)' % pattern,
                         r'<a href="#\1">\1</a>',
                         txt)
        txt.replaceWith(newtext)
print(soup)
```

Which unfortunately returns

```
<html><body><p>&lt;a href="#replace"&gt;replace&lt;/a&gt; this string </p></body></html>
```

Whereas I am looking for:

```
<html><body><p><a href="#replace">replace</a> this string </p></body></html>
```

Is there a way in which I can tell BeautifulSoup not to escape the link elements?

A simple regex to replace will not do here because I will eventually not only have one pattern that I want to replace but multiple. This is why I decided to use BeautifulSoup to exclude everything that already is a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create new tag using [`new_tag`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup-new-string-and-new-tag) use [`insert_after`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) to insert part of your `text` after your newly created `a` tag.

```
for txt in soup.find_all(text=True):
    if re.search(pattern, txt, re.I) and txt.parent.name != 'a':
        newtag = soup.new_tag('a')
        newtag.attrs['href'] = "#{}".format(pattern)
        newtag.string = pattern
        txt.replace_with(newtag)
        newtag.insert_after(txt.replace(pattern, ""))
```

Comment: Thank you. This does almost what I am looking for. The only problem is that it wraps the whole text. So the output now is ```<a href="#replace">replace this string </a>```  but I am looking for ```<a href="#replace">replace</a> this string ``` Would this also be possible?

Comment: I updated my question to make clear what result I am looking for.

Comment: Note that this assumes that the text is always at the beginning of the string. If adapted this so that it works for strings in any location as well: http://pastebin.com/K9NtXtdu