# Editing attributes without escaping characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, webflow

Background: I am creating websites in Webflow, and then exporting them to be integrated with a PHP backend. Webflow's default file structure is different than our backend, so I'm using Python & BeautifulSoup to help correct some tedious things before actually 'integrating' the exported code.

The first thing I'm trying to solve is changing all image `src`s to 'images/xxx' rather than '../images/xxx', which I was able to do like this:

```
img['src'] = img['src'].replace('../images/', 'images/')
```

Now I'd like to find all the links and replace their `href`s with the structure we use on the backend that looks like this:

```
<a href="<?=$website_info->url?>/page"></a>
```

I've been able to find all the links in BS without any issues, and I'm trying to replace their `href`s like this:

```
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for link in links:
    link['href'] = '<?=$website_info->url?>/page'
    print(link)
```

but that results in output like this, with every `<` and `>` replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively:

```
<a class="inner-page-nav-link w-nav-link" href="&lt;?=$website_info-&gt;url?&gt;/link">Page Name</a>
```

Does anyone know how I could replace the link `href`s without the `<` and `>` characters being escaped like this?

Comment: Does this help: [Replace text without escaping in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692601/4985733)

Comment: @MartinEvans Thank you! I saw that, and tried to go that route but ended up having some trouble because all the links also have other attributes (classes and other custom attributes).

Comment: Could you update the question to include a bigger example to recreate that?